Docker error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
I've recently cloned my repository to a new device. My repository is run in a docker environment. However, despite having one successful docker image build on this device, whenever I try to build a new Docker image(by running docker build . ) I encounter this error when installing in requirements.txt:
Dockerfile:30
--------------------
  28 |     # Install dependencies
  29 |     COPY requirements.txt .
  30 | >>> RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
  31 |
  32 |     # Copy project
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2

I haven't been able to find anything related to error code 2 online. I've restarted Docker and ran the command at least 10 times. I've also increased pip timeout to 2 mins using set PIP_TIMEOUT=120 but it still results in the same error.
Here is the full traceback(along with the last package being installed:
Collecting nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.5.0.96 (from torch==2.0.1->-r requirements.txt (line 45))
179.9   Downloading nvidia_cudnn_cu11-8.5.0.96-2-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (557.1 MB)
239.0      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╸                      250.1/557.1 MB 1.1 MB/s eta 0:04:38
239.0 ERROR: Exception:
239.0 Traceback (most recent call last):
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
239.0     yield
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 561, in read
239.0     data = self._fp_read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
239.0            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 527, in _fp_read
239.0     return self._fp.read(amt) if amt is not None else self._fp.read()
239.0            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 466, in read
239.0     s = self.fp.read(amt)
239.0         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 706, in readinto
239.0     return self._sock.recv_into(b)
239.0            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1278, in recv_into
239.0     return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
239.0            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1134, in read
239.0     return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
239.0            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0 TimeoutError: The read operation timed out
239.0
239.0 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
239.0
239.0 Traceback (most recent call last):
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 169, in exc_logging_wrapper
239.0     status = run_func(*args)
239.0              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 248, in wrapper
239.0     return func(self, options, args)
239.0            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 377, in run
239.0     requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
239.0                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
239.0     result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
239.0                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
239.0     state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
239.0             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 427, in resolve
239.0     failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name)
239.0                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 239, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
239.0     criteria = self._get_updated_criteria(candidate)
239.0                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 230, in _get_updated_criteria
239.0     self._add_to_criteria(criteria, requirement, parent=candidate)
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
239.0     if not criterion.candidates:
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 156, in __bool__
239.0     return bool(self._sequence)
239.0            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
239.0     return any(self)
239.0            ^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
239.0     return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
239.0            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
239.0     candidate = func()
239.0                 ^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
239.0     self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
239.0                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 293, in __init__
239.0     super().__init__(
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
239.0     self.dist = self._prepare()
239.0                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 225, in _prepare
239.0     dist = self._prepare_distribution()
239.0            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 304, in _prepare_distribution
239.0     return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
239.0            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 516, in prepare_linked_requirement
239.0     return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
239.0            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 587, in _prepare_linked_requirement
239.0     local_file = unpack_url(
239.0                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 166, in unpack_url
239.0     file = get_http_url(
239.0            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 107, in get_http_url
239.0     from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
239.0                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 147, in __call__
239.0     for chunk in chunks:
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 53, in _rich_progress_bar
239.0     for chunk in iterable:
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
239.0     for chunk in response.raw.stream(
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 622, in stream
239.0     data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
239.0            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 560, in read
239.0     with self._error_catcher():
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 155, in __exit__
239.0     self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
239.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
239.0     raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
239.0 pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
------
Dockerfile:30
--------------------
  28 |     # Install dependencies
  29 |     COPY requirements.txt .
  30 | >>> RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
  31 |
  32 |     # Copy project
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/default/default/xkiouh9bexjvwvhk6p67lie73

The error seems to only ever occur when installing pytorch( and specifically the nvidia_cudnn_ ... line) so I'm not sure if it is a pytorch specific error.
Here is my Dockerfile:
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-bullseye

# Set environment variables
ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR off
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV COLUMNS 80

#install Debian and other dependencies that are required to run python apps(eg. git, python-magic).
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y --force-yes \
 nano python3-pip gettext chrpath libssl-dev libxft-dev \
 libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev  libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev\
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmagic-dev
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ffmpeg


# Set working directory for Docker image
WORKDIR /code/

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . .

And here is a section of my requirements.txt
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
sympy==1.12
termcolor==2.3.0
tiktoken==0.3.3
torch==2.0.1
tqdm==4.66.1


It seems it was either related to wherever nvidia_cudnn_ ... was being downloaded from or a local network issue. I simply tried several more times and moved a little close to the access point and it worked. I also increased the pip timeout to 300.
